# What's the difference between $-81^{3/2}$ & $(-81)^{3/2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, exponentiation, radicals, associativity

Calculating $81^{3/2}$, I got $729$ (not saying it is correct, but I am trying :) ).  Would $-81^{3/2}$ just be the opposite ($-729$) and does it make a difference if $-81$ was placed inside a pair of parentheses $(-81)^{3/2}$?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you

Comment: See [Powers and Roots of Complex numbers](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Roots.aspx). Also note that: $-2^3\ne (-2)^3=(-1)^3 2^3$

Comment: @TymaGaidash When I put both into the calculator I get the same product (-8). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @יהודה  You are right, Wait that was a bad example, it does not matter for odd integers,  try doing: $-4=-2^2\ne (-2)^2=(-1)^2 2^2=4$ instead.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Alright thank you. So $(-1)^22^{2}$ is the same as writing & $(-2)^2$?

Comment: @יהודה Using real number properties remember that:$$a^n b^n=a•a • a •… • b • b • b •…=(a • b)(a • b)(a • b)(…)=(ab)^n\mathop\implies^{a=-1,b=2,n=2} (-1)^2 2^2=(-1 • 2)^2=(-2)^2 $$ using the associativity property of multiplication. Sorry for the “ •” notation.

Comment: $(-81)^\frac{3}{2}=(9i)^3=-729i$

Comment: @herbsteinberg Peace and thank you, beloved. Where did you get i from?

Comment: $(-81)^\frac{1}{2}=9i$

Comment: @herbsteinberg Please forgive me, I don't follow. Do you have to put i (or a variable)?

Comment: Definition: $i=\sqrt{-1}$.   What level of math are you in?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Definitely not on your level Mr. Skywalker lol....seriously in all my years of ever doing math I have never seen "i" being utilized to represent the square root of -1. Right now I am in intermediate algebra.

Comment: I suspect sometime in intermediate algebra you will learn about the square root of negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can think of the $-$ sign as the following words: "the opposite of".

In this case, $-1$ is the opposite of $1$, which just means it's the number that, when added to $1$, results in $0$.

Similarly, $-\pi$ is the opposite of $\pi$, the number that, when added to $\pi$, results in $0$.

In your question, $-81^{3/2}$ is a negative number, the number that, when added to $81^{3/2}$, results in $0$. You can simplify $81^{3/2}=729$ to see that $-81^{3/2}$ then must be $-729$.

However, $(-81)^{3/2}$ has the $-$ sign inside the parentheses. This means that the "opposite of" quality applies to $81$ and THEN we apply an exponent. Using properties of exponents, we do get that this is equal to $(-1)^{3/2}(81)^{3/2}$. If you are unfamiliar with complex numbers, then just saying that you can't take the square root of the $-1$ is sufficient for this, and is enough to see that this is very different than the original $-81^{3/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also new to Mathematics but I will try and explain in simple terms:

Using exponent rules we can say that $\left(-81\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is equal to $\sqrt[2]{\left(-81\right)^{3}}$. In this case $\left(-81\right)^{3}$ will give us a negative number, so calculating $\left(-81\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is only possible with the use of imaginary numbers.

It does make a difference if you put it in parentheses. If you type $-81^{\frac{3}{2}}$ in a calculator it will give you the anwer $-729$; this is only because it determines the expression as $-\left(81^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$ meaning it will first evaluate the expression $\sqrt[2]{81^{3}}$ which will result in a positive number and then *multiply it by $-1$*.

More info: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-eighth-grade-math/cc-8th-numbers-operations/exponents-with-negative-bases/v/exponents-with-negative-bases

Cheers,
Tom

(I am a math 'noob' so if I've missed something please let me know.)

Comment: Thank you, Tom. So within the parenthesis negative number (-a) with an exponent (-a), ^x will be classified as imaginary.  Copy that.

Comment: @יהודה That's exactly right, hope you are satisfied with the answer :)

Comment: I am and thank you again. Even though you claim that you are new at this, it seems as though you have a great grasp of the concept.  Keep it up!!!